# XAML designer error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' to type 'System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter'."

Tags: wpf, xaml, markup-extensions

I am using an open-source XAML Markup Extension to populate a `<ComboBox>` from a declared `enum` type, but in the designer I get these errors (blue-squiggle underlined text):

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' to type 'System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter'.

Here is the XAML that causes the error (the error is on the `ItemsSource` attribute and value):

```
<ComboBox
    ItemsSource="{local:Enumerate {x:Type p:FoobarEnum}, {StaticResource e2s}}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding Foobar, Converter={StaticResource e2s}}"
/>
```

The `e2s` resource is declared in a ResourceDictionary:

```
<v:EnumToStringConverter x:Key="e2s" />
```

And the `Enumerate` markup extension [is from this GitHub project](https://github.com/YohDeadfall/Enumerate/).

```
[ValueConversion( typeof( Enum ), typeof( String ) )]
public class EnumToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public Object Convert(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ...
    }
    public Object ConvertBack(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ...
    }
}

[MarkupExtensionReturnType( typeof( IEnumerable<Object> ) )]
public sealed class EnumerateExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public EnumerateExtension()
    {
    }

    public EnumerateExtension(Type type, Object converter)
    {
        ...
        // converter needs to be Object otherwise WPF complains with other errors
    }
}
```

The weird thing is that this actually works when the program runs and the `EnumerateExtension` correctly loads the enum's members (localised too) into the ComboBox.

Answer (score -1):

Change your ItemsSource attribute value to :

```
ItemsSource="{local:Enumerate Type={x:Type p:FoobarEnum}, Convertor={StaticResource e2s}}"
```

This will work 110%.

Problem is XAML parser is confused to figure out which one to use for Type, and which one for Convertor. Ordering and explicit mentioning is important in XAML.

Comment: When I do that I get this designer and build error: "Unknown property 'Converter' for type 'MS.Internal.Markup.MarkupExtensionParser+UnknownMarkupExtension' encountered while parsing a Markup Extension."